# Can't we lazily do view::filter before view::chunk?

Tags: c++, c++11, lazy-evaluation, range-v3

This won't compile:

```
auto out = view::closed_iota(1,100)
                | view::filter([](auto item){ return item % 10; })
                | view::chunk(10);

for (auto&& rng : out) {
    std::cout << rng << "\n";
}
```

Error:

```
In file included from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/rangesv3/trunk/include/range/v3/view/chunk.hpp:144:36: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const _end_::fn'
                return adaptor{n_, ranges::end(this->base())};
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

[godbolt.org/g/PhcdGc](https://godbolt.org/g/PhcdGc)

---

I wonder what are concepts behind this behavior?

If this does not satisfy concept like [this](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/8ccd974b5cbb91dc9de7ab969abd568fcf569019/include/range/v3/view/chunk.hpp#L408), why is there no alert shows up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the `chunk` view. It is expecting its base range to be `const`-iterable, but the `filter` view is not. I'll fix it. Thanks for the report!

EDIT: This *was* a bug. It has now been fixed on master by [the brilliant and insightful Casey's PR 808](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/808).

Comment: LOL. Thank you, oh brilliant and insightful Casey.